# sorting time in python

Tags: python, sorting, matplotlib, time

How can I make the plot x axis from 7am to 7pm and not as continuous time??

intemp. the data frame

```
time,base,urban.blue,intensive.green,extensive.green,max.built,cool.pavement,combined
12:00 am,28.35375055,28.34980961,28.34492091,28.34377128,28.36277791,28.22387471,28.177143100000006
1:00 am,28.11415367,28.11045083,28.10638452,28.10536831,28.1225423,27.9967994,27.95348082
2:00 am,27.87064883,27.86709162,27.86385966,27.86298143,27.87838956,27.76372643,27.7234331
3:00 am,27.62453793,27.62111962,27.61856862,27.61781664,27.63181702,27.52770491,27.49001164
4:00 am,27.37470555,27.37134243,27.36956908,27.36888839,27.38141603,27.28607247,27.25139494
5:00 am,27.11904617,27.11572198,27.11470691,27.11412249,27.12531469,27.03953163,27.00702066
6:00 am,26.86420037,26.86128349,26.8595799,26.858049400000002,26.87072845,26.78933635,26.75818533
7:00 am,26.84665666,26.84400906,26.83882232,26.83517825,26.85609531,26.73453118,26.70670816
8:00 am,26.81063843,26.81522137,26.79957211,26.79587239,26.81530735,26.72526586,26.70687839
9:00 am,27.08944918,27.09222016,27.07334707,27.06563655,27.10052843,26.88516356,26.86414915
10:00 am,27.40958611,27.40882987,27.3879663,27.378301300000004,27.42423438,27.11260049,27.08420222
11:00 am,27.77257755,27.76849956,27.74768666,27.73799223,27.78946719,27.39854854,27.35740361
12:00 pm,28.18696598,28.1794838,28.16091861,28.15189694,28.20700555,27.76856114,27.7117156
1:00 pm,28.59681336,28.58725474,28.56625252,28.55684719,28.61773029,28.17529437,28.10714
2:00 pm,28.99501505,28.98560048,28.96130064,28.95143734,29.01307443,28.58055809,28.506905
3:00 pm,29.40999138,29.40179654,29.37339395,29.362621100000002,29.430033,28.97680313,28.89177323
4:00 pm,29.77360707,29.76782519,29.73757765,29.72552875,29.79287685,29.37285801,29.28199909
5:00 pm,29.84642297,29.84192386,29.81377907,29.80098853,29.86477516,29.5037548,29.413809399999998
6:00 pm,29.68795442,29.68179112,29.66455259,29.65723539,29.7021414,29.41447444,29.33763567
7:00 pm,29.48694108,29.48136961,29.46902252,29.46482315,29.499612699999997,29.2602974,29.192650099999998
8:00 pm,29.27154538,29.26641314,29.25653582,29.25391688,29.28335453,29.07521112,29.01322732
9:00 pm,29.04794672,29.04323447,29.03476464,29.03279683,29.059109600000003,28.87135168,28.81324521
10:00 pm,28.82099571,28.81654141,28.80963965,28.80802037,28.83139559,28.66122489,28.60665971
11:00 pm,28.58917543,28.58501013,28.57906856,28.57770256,28.59894401,28.44603835,28.39500312


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sn


fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True,figsize=(8,6))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(1, 1)
plt.style.use('default')

f_ax1 (wide)
f_ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, :])
f_ax1.plot(intemp["time"][0:23],intemp["cool.pavement"][0:23],'-r',alpha=1,label='cool.pavement')
f_ax1.plot(intemp["time"][0:23],intemp["base"][0:23],'--k',label='base')
f_ax1.plot(intemp["time"][0:23],intemp["urban.blue"][0:23],'-b',alpha=0.1,label='urban.blue')
f_ax1.plot(intemp["time"][0:23],intemp["max.built"][0:23],'-b',alpha=0.3,label='max.built')
f_ax1.plot(intemp["time"][0:23],intemp["intensive.green"][0:23],'-b',alpha=0.6,label='intensive.green')
f_ax1.plot(intemp["time"][0:23],intemp["extensive.green"][0:23],'-b',alpha=0.8,label='extensive.green')
f_ax1.plot(intemp["time"][0:23],intemp["combined"][0:23],'-b',alpha=1,label='combined')
f_ax1.set_title('Hourly Maximum Indoor Air Temperature')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
f_ax1.set_ylabel ("Air Temperature (°C)")
f_ax1.legend(frameon=False, loc='best', ncol=2)
f_ax1.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.1', color='grey')
plt.xlim(0,23)<-- THIS DIDN"T WORK
```

dataframes

Answer (score 0):

The value was retrieved with `get_xticks()`. Your specification is not wrong. For example, `f_ax1.set_xticks(1,21)` is correctly controlled.

```
x = f_ax1.get_xticks()
print(x)
f_ax1.set_xlim(1,21)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank so much for your prompt help. In fact, I got around that by changing the index order by rearranging the time col to start on 7:00am instead of 12:00am